# Pegar o restante das casas decimais e realizar uma conversão

Tags: javascript, html

Sou bem leigo em javascript, mas acho que dá para fazer isso nesta linguagem. Tentei de uma forma bem trivial, mas não obtive sucesso.
Basicamente tenho um sistema que converte a quantidade em kg para caixas de biscoitos, por exemplo:

```js
function bisc_salg(){
 p3 = document.getElementById("multiplicando3").value;
 p4 = document.getElementById("multiplicador3").value;
 r = p3/p4;
 document.getElementById("resultado3").value = r.toFixed(3);
 }
```

```html
<form id="bisc_salg" class="box_Branco">
<p class="desc_item"> Biscoito Salgado Cream Cracker </p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Qtde." class="qtde_Req" id="multiplicando3" onChange="bisc_salg();"> 
  <input type="text" class="invisible" id="multiplicador3" readonly="readonly" value=4.8 onChange="bisc_salg();"> =
  <input type="text" class="retorno" id="resultado3" readonly="readonly"> caixas
</form>
```

Vamos supor que eu tenha 14.8 kg e jogando nesse sistema eu obtenho: 3.083 que significa 3 caixas inteiras e um pacote de biscoito. Ou seja, cada pacote tem 400 gramas. Como eu pego esse resto da casa decimal e converto em pacotes? Mais ou menos teria que retornar:

3 caixas e 1 pacote.

Os dados resumidos são:
Cada caixa tem 12 pacotes de biscoitos e 4.8 Kg; cada biscoito tem 400 gramas.

Comment: Acho que essa conta tá errada. Se um pacote tem 200g, tirando o pacote extra, ficaria 19kg, que são 19 mil gramas... dividindo por 200g de cada pacote, dá 95 pacotes, logo não dá pra dividir 95 em 3 caixas.

Comment: Perdão, já efetuei a correção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o operador módulo `%` que retorna o resto da divisão...

```
9 % 3 // retorna 0
10 % 3 // retorna 1
11 % 3 // retorna 2
12 % 3 // retorna 0
```

Então se dividir o resultado do módulo pelo peso do pacote (0.4kg) ficará com a quantidade de pacotes...

```js
console.log('pacotes:', Math.round(14.8 % 4.8 / 0.4));
console.log('pacotes:', Math.round(15.2 % 4.8 / 0.4));
```

O `Math.round` é por causa do erro da divisão com pontos flutuantes...
[Veja mais aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)